# override stock update function in PrestaShop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-helper-classes

I want to override stock update function of the core files of PrestaShop. I don't know where it is located in the files.

basically, I want to call an external API when the stock of the products is updated. (only when the stock is updated,  like when a product is purchased or manually product stock update through backend ).

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you already researched this topic on other sites? Please provide an example of what you have done so we can show you how to properly modify your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to override anything. It's better to create a module and use available hooks to manage your requirements, such as `actionObjectOrderAddAfter`, `actionOrderStatusPostUpdate`, `actionOrderStatusUpdate` within front-end and `actionObjectProductAddAfter`, `actionObjectProductDeleteAfter`, `actionObjectProductUpdateAfter`.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't create the module, there is some limitation. the solution should be withing override.